# Charge distribution/movement in an insulator

Tags: charge, static-electricity, electrostatic

The way I understand it, net charge in a conductor spreads out evenly over the surface, while for a charged insulating object, the charge will tend to stay clustered around the spot where it was charged.  Still, even an object that's considered an insulator could still have some limited electrical conductivity which could allow charge movement at a slow rate.  Is there a way of calculating how long it would take for charge to spread out over the surface of an object with a given electrical resistance, surface area and net charge?

Comment: You need the capacitance, too. Because that's what the charge is "stored" in.

Comment: I see.  But how do you do calculations about this?  I get I=V/R, but when you're talking about this, I'm not sure how you would calculate charge flow.

Comment: You first had to model the surface as a flat network of identical resistors with caps to ambient connected at the vertexes. Then load an area of caps at t=0 and see how the charge is distributed through the network as time flies. It's possible to find a formula for extremely simple cases (sphere, cylinder and loading a single point etc.) already using a lot of differential math but in general, this depends on both the 3D shape of the surface and the size and shape of the area initially charged. So you had to simulate it with the finite elements method.

Comment: (If you only expected a qualitative answer, the charge distribution over time and space follows an exponential decay function. So the answer is: it takes an infinite amount of time but for practical cases the time constant is \$R'\cdot C'\$ and after \$5\cdot R'\cdot C'\$, all the interesting things had already happened. To find out what R' and C' are for a given shape is the hard part.)

Comment: I see.  Could you give an example for say, a charged electrically insulating flat plane?  Seems like it would be the simplest example (maybe).

Comment: Honestly no. I'm a bit rusty in doing the math correctly.